# How #if 0 && defined(_LP64) be true?

Tags: c++, c, macros, typedef, c-preprocessor

From the header file ncurses.h, what is the use of `#if` as I think `#if 0` will always return  false and control will always go the `#else` part?

```
#if 0 && defined(_LP64)
typedef unsigned chtype;
typedef unsigned mmask_t;
#else
typedef unsigned long chtype;
typedef unsigned long mmask_t;
#endif
```

Comment: Alternative way to comment out large sections of things. (can nest unlike `/*`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will never be true. It's likely that `_LP64` used to be relevant, but it stopped being so, and to comment out all the related code, the programmer anded in a 0.

Answer (score 8):

It can never be true. It is likely written like this as a way to comment out chunks of code instead of using /* */ commenting.